# Binary Star question

Tags: binary-star, star-systems

Is it POSSIBLE that we are a binary system? I have been doing research into this topic and it seems we may infact be a binary system. If we are, what effects would a massive body comming into our system be? And are these effects happening now?

Answer (score 1):

Since every object in the known universe which has mass has an infinite gravitational field every object in the universe affects one another. 
Every star in our surrounding affects Our solar system but the relative proximity of the sun masks these effects to us. 
However if the sun would be a part of a binary system of stars

1. Our planet should have been affected by it because a star is a much larger mass when compared to the planets.
2. Since the star and our sun interact with each other they would produce a noticeable wobble.
3. Any such star would definitely be very close to the sun so as to be able to influence it and hence easily visible yet no evidence has been found for this.

So for now one can say that we and the sun are not part of any binary star system which has been (if it exists) undiscovered till recently